# Not able to install any version of netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I get this message after downloading any version of netbeans. I am not getting what the problem is.

```
Could not open netbeans6.9-ml-java-linux.sh
Archive type not supported
```

I have tried this for 3-4 versions of netbeans, but the same problem occurs.

Please Help

Comment: Is your issue you just can't run the file `netbeans6.9-ml-java-linux.sh` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try typing in the terminal

```
bash ./netbeans6.9-ml-java-linux.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use terminal. Change directory to the directory where you have downloaded the **netbeans6.9-ml-java-linux.sh** file.

```
cd /home/username/Downloads/
```

Then run this.

```
sudo chmod a+x netbeans6.9-ml-java-linux.sh
```

It will enable execution access to the file. After that you should do this to install.

```
sudo bash netbeans6.9-ml-java-linux.sh
```

Comment: `sudo netbeans6.9-ml-java-linux.sh` is enough. ;)

Comment: Yeah. But Explaining things are important, isn't it ? :)

Comment: The first line in the `sh` file is `#!/bin/sh`, a shebang. Therefore after a `chmod`, a `bash …` isn't necessary.